# transform.position in Update method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isUp)
        {
            ball.transform.position += upVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        else if (isDown)
        {
            ball.transform.position += downVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        else if (isLeft)
        {
            ball.transform.position += rightVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        else if (isRight)
            ball.transform.position += leftVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    }

    public void MouseDown()
    {
        isUp = isDown = isLeft = isRight = false;

        if (this.name == "Up")
        {
            ball.transform.position += upVector;
            isUp = true;
        }
        else if (this.name == "Down")
        {
            ball.transform.position += downVector;
            isDown = true;
        }
        else if (this.name == "Right")
        {
            ball.transform.position += rightVector;
            isRight = true;
        }
        else if (this.name == "Left")
        {
            ball.transform.position += leftVector;
            isLeft = true;
        }
    }
```

I can't understand why when I click "Right" button after "Left" button, the ball doesn't move.

When I click "Right" button, it moves left well, but when I click "Left" button after it, the ball doesn't move. It's same when I click Up and Down.

Comment: when are you calling MouseDown? and what are your rightVector variables? [mcve]

Comment: a bit erro prone to go by strings and let all buttons run all checks ... why not rather have a simple `isPressed` and rather expose a single direction vector in the Inspector?

Comment: I made four arrow buttons, and MouseDown is each onClick event. Vector3 rightVector = Vector3.right * speed